# How do i access an array within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an associative array that has is an array that contains a field called `id` and another called `data`. In the `id` there will be a value, and in `data` another associative array will be stored.

```
array1 = []
array2 = []

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
      array2 [i] = {number1: 31, number2: 29, number3: 31}
      array1 [i] = {id: i, data: array2 [i]}
}
```

**How do I access the "number1" of index 0, of array1?**

Comment: `array1[0].data.number1` (no index on `data`)

Comment: @Thomas write an answer to vote it, since it has helped me correctly.

Comment: A good question contains _sample input_ and the _desired output_ - you have provided neither.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [access array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements) you specify the index number in brackets. When it comes to [accessing object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties), you can use the property name with bracket notation, or you can use dot notation. See the comments in the code below:

```js
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  array2[i] = {
    number1: 31,
    number2: 29,
    number3: 31
  }
  array1[i] = {
    id: i,
    data: array2[i]
  }
}

//Access the array element by specifying it's index:
var el = array1[0];

//Since el is a reference to an Object, we have 2 options for accessing it's properties:
//Option 1 (dot notation):
console.log(el.data.number1);

//Option 2 (property names): 
console.log(el['data']['number1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, instead of accessing by index, you access by your fields that you have created:

```
var a = array1[data];
```

Hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using `array1[0].data.number1`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the answer you are looking for.

```js
//How do I access the "number1" of index 0, of array1?
array1 = [];
array2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
      array2 [i] = {number1: 31, number2: 29, number3: 31}
      array1 [i] = {id: i, data: array2 [i]}
}

console.log(array1[0].data['number1']);
```